# UITableView + Core Data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I started to work (learn) to handle a `UITableView` + Core Data, and I started to read something about it, and after I would start to write a little sample app, where I can push a button and then the data will display in the `tableView`.

My problem is that I have programmed it correctly, I think, Xcode doesn't show me any warnings or errors etc. But it doesn't work.

Can anybody tell me why this code doesn't work?

Project:
http://www.sendspace.com/file/ohc1kn

EDIT:
If you dont set: `self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = nil;`

The following error is shown:

> 2013-02-17 16:45:05.480 tableView+Coredata[1533:207] *** Assertion
>   failure in -[UITableView
>   _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1912.3/UITableView.m:6072
>       2013-02-17 16:45:05.481 tableView+Coredata[1533:207] CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the
>   delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:.  UITableView dataSource must return a cell from tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: with userInfo (null)

---

Code is used to insert a NewObject to the Database and TableView and if I perform that I get the error above.

```
// Create a new instance of the entity managed by the fetched results controller.
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.fetchedResultsController managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchRequest] entity];
NSManagedObject *newManagedObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:[entity name] inManagedObjectContext:context];
// If appropriate, configure the new managed object.
// Normally you should use accessor methods, but using KVC here avoids the need to add a custom class to the template.
[newManagedObject setValue:[NSDate date] forKey:@"timeStamp"];
// Save the context.
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    /*
     Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.

     abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development. 
     */
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: I'm unwilling to download a random zip file. Please post your code as text.

Comment: Please edit your question to describe what doesn't work. Is it an error? Data in wrong cells? What exactly is the problem (one problem per question)? Be specific. And add the code around your problem to your question.

Comment: And now fix the code indentation, please.

Answer (score 1):

1 mistake is the missing tableView parameter: `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

fix that and then tell us what exactly doesn't work / what you would expect your app to do

Answer (score 0):

You should provide other details here. It's not easy to understand what is going on, but in the meantime I have few considerations.

First, are you using `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:` method? If not you should `alloc-init` a cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Then, override in the correct manner `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` like the following

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // your code here...
    return cell;
}
```